# Security issues about running VirtualBox with bridged-adapter

Tags: ssh, networking, virtualbox

I set up a Gnu/Linux VirtualBox, and I configured networking to support both NAT and bridged connections, in order to ssh to it remotely from a different PC in my network.

Since an IP was assigned to my bridged connection, that I use to connect to the guest OS, 
is there a way for anyone outside my local network to connect to it as well?

Answer (score 0):

Any network traffic that can reach your physical network adapter can potentially reach the VM. That is the point of a vbox bridged network.

Ask yourself, "is there a way for anyone outside my local network to connect to my host system?" The answer to your posted question is the same as the answer to this one I have posed.